# Cannot connect to MongoDB within an Android App deployed via Eclipse (Mac)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mongodb

I'm building an Android application and want to connect to a MongoDB but I have no luck. I'm working in Eclipse (on MacOSX).

I followed the [tutorial from the Mongo site](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/java/import-data/).

I downloaded Mongo and ran it using: `sudo mongod`

I have added the following jar files as stated in the tutorial: `mongo-java-driver-3.0.4.jar and Bson-3.0.4.jar`.

Every time I ran the code `MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();` I get this error as shown in image below.

[image: Error code]

Comment: you did not add `mongo-java-driver-3.0.4.jar` as a library for your Android project. it needs to be "integrated" so - once deployed on the target device - it is available at runtime. Are you using Gradle as a Build-Tool?

Comment: It is really recommended you use Android Studio as your development environment since Eclipse is not officially supported anymore.

Comment: yes I am using build tool from Eclipse and GenyMotion emulator to run the app

Comment: Ok thx i will try with Android Studio, I didn't know Eclipse is not supported anymore